# `div` with display mode set to `inline-block` gets forced onto next line despite setting margin to 0

Tags: html, css

Suppose we have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  color: white;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column">
</div>

<div class="right-column"></div>
```

I am setting the width of the `div` with class `left-column` to 30% of the viewport width, and the width of the `div` with class `right-column` to 70% of the viewport width. Since I'm using border box sizing, an overall margin of 0 and display mode to `inline-block` I expect for these boxes to appear adjacent to each other in the inline direction. Strangely, the `div` with class `right-column` appears underneath the `div` with class `left-column`.

I feel like I am not accounting for some additional horizontal space which somehow gets rendered and forces the `right-column` onto the next line. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you missing `padding`  on `body`/`html` or maybe space/newline between your inline divs? Y u no use `flex`?

Comment: Padding is irrelevant here because I'm using `border-box`  sizing. Why should I use `flex` for such a simple example and how is it relevant to this particular question?

Comment: Yes, it's space/newline between divs.

Comment: OK, just remove spaces and newlines  like this: `<div class="left-column">
</div><div class="right-column"></div>`. Also no need to be rude.

Comment: @Kosh Not fully reading the question and throwing out incomplete, unhelpful comments like "Y u no use `flex`" is also pretty rude. I'd rather you didn't comment at all in that case.

Comment: I'm happy that you've got a good answer (which suggests either removing spaces or using flex). I use firefox therefore I missed the scrollbar for webkit, incomplete, my bad. You know, StackOverflow is a dangerous place -- people may ask questions in comments, so take care of your vulnerable self. And have a great day, sincerely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A scroll bar also takes up space horizontal space.
Here is an example that hides the scroll bar for webkit based browsers.

You should see that they align next to each other.
(i've also removed any enters/spaces between the `<div>` elements, these take up space as well, like @kosh mentioned.)

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  color: white;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 100vh;
  color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column">
</div><div class="right-column"></div>
```

## flex-box

You might be able to use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to achieve the same without having to worry about scroll bars.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 30 30 auto;
  background-color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.right-column {
  flex: 70 70 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column">
</div>
<div class="right-column"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

1. add border-box to all elements and before and after
2. Use % for width as vw/vh counts full viewport size including scrollbar etc.
3. set font size to 0
4. do not add any space, whitespace in between the inline-block elements

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: rgb(41, 52, 72);
  border: 5px solid green;
}
.left-column, .right-column {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-column"></div><div class="right-column"></div>
```